# How to select records b/w two month names in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am very much new to MYSQL,so i had written something like this.

modified_date is in month like for ex:2017-03-24 13:38:11

```
select * from TableName  
where  monthname(modified_date) between  monthname(a.modified_date)= "March" 
and monthname(modified_date)="June" ;
```

For the above query i am getting an error(Please refer the pic)
[image].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple fix here would be to use the numerical `MONTH` function:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName  
WHERE MONTH(modified_date) BETWEEN 3 AND 6;
```

But really you might also want to restrict the year as well, in which case you could use:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName  
WHERE
    MONTH(modified_date) BETWEEN 3 AND 6 AND
    YEAR(modified_date) IN (2017, ...);
```

I personally don't like using `MONTH` and `YEAR` for the very reason that it splits the date logic into multiple places.  Yet another option, if you only wanted to target 2017, would be to just use date literals:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName  
WHERE
    modified_date >= '2017-03-01' AND modified_date < '2017-07-01';
```

Comment: Is it a bad practice to select b/w month names and if so how to select just for that month.

Like,only for month 2 or 3 not b/w 2 and 3.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of taking month name get the month(number) using **[`MONTH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)** function. And use it in the `WHERE` clause.

**Query**

```
select * from TableName  
where month(modified_date) between 3 and 6;
```

Comment: Is it a bad practice to select b/w month names and if so how to select just for that month.

Like,only for month 2 or 3 not b/w 2 and 3.

Comment: @Prash : Change the condition in `WHERE` clause accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

**you can use this query**

```
select event from date 
where month(date) between 3 and 6;
```

i use sample table like below

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM TableName  WHERE MONTH(modified_date) BETWEEN 3 AND 6;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.